# Fatal error when running roboVM with libGDX app

Tags: java, ios, maven, libgdx, robovm

I'm trying to run my libGDX app with roboVM. However, when I either try running it on the ios simulator or on a provisioned ios device, I get the following fatal error:

```
[INFO] Building RoboVM app for: ios (thumbv7)
[INFO] Compiling RoboVM app, this could take a while, especially the first time round
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000012d10221a, pid=243, tid=6403
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [librobovm-llvm4029610622620581913.dylib+0x30b21a]  _ZL16getCopyFromPartsRN4llvm12SelectionDAGENS_5SDLocEPKNS_7SDValueEjNS_3MVTENS_3EVTEPKNS_5ValueENS_3ISD8NodeTypeE+0x161a
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/<user>/<project>/hs_err_pid243.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Abort trap: 6
```

In case it's important, the error file with more information mentioned in the error is [this](http://pastebin.com/JTf405Qy).

I'm using the robovm maven plugin, and am using this maven command:

```
mvn clean integration-test -Pios
```

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>[parent groupid]</groupId>
        <artifactId>[parent artifactid]</artifactId>
        <version>[parent version]</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>[artifactid]</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <mainClass>[Main Class]</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>[core groupid]</groupId>
            <artifactId>[core artifactid]</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.badlogicgames.gdx</groupId>
            <artifactId>gdx</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.badlogicgames.gdx</groupId>
            <artifactId>gdx-backend-robovm</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>../assets</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                    <argLine>-Djava.library.path=${project.build.directory}/natives/</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.robovm</groupId>
                <artifactId>robovm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.11.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <config>
                        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        <os>ios</os>
                        <arch>x86</arch>
                    </config>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>iphone-sim</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>iphone-sim</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and my robovm.xml looks like this:

```
<config>
    <executableName>${app.executable}</executableName>
    <mainClass>${app.mainclass}</mainClass>
    <os>ios</os>
    <arch>thumbv7</arch>
    <target>ios</target>
    <iosInfoPList>Info.plist.xml</iosInfoPList>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>../assets</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <skipPngCrush>true</skipPngCrush>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <forceLinkClasses>
        <pattern>com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.*</pattern>
        <pattern>org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLProvider</pattern>
        <pattern>org.apache.harmony.security.provider.cert.DRLCertFactory</pattern>
        <pattern>com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider</pattern>
        <pattern>org.apache.harmony.security.provider.crypto.CryptoProvider</pattern>
        <pattern>org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.JSSEProvider</pattern>
        <pattern>com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyStore</pattern>
        <pattern>org.apache.harmony.security.provider.cert.X509CertFactoryImpl</pattern>
        <pattern>com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi</pattern>
        <pattern>org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLMessageDigestJDK$MD5</pattern>
    </forceLinkClasses>
    <libs>
        <lib>../res/libgdx.a</lib>
        <lib>../res/libObjectAL.a</lib>
    </libs>
    <frameworks>
        <framework>UIKit</framework>
        <framework>OpenGLES</framework>
        <framework>QuartzCore</framework>
        <framework>CoreGraphics</framework>
        <framework>OpenAL</framework>
        <framework>AudioToolbox</framework>
        <framework>AVFoundation</framework>
    </frameworks>
</config>
```

I haven't the slightest idea what this error means. I googled around and couldn't find any mention of anyone getting a similar error, so I'm at a loss as to what to do. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

EDIT: It seems to be compiling `com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.style.BCStyle` when the error occurs. This is shown when debugging is enabled:

```
[INFO] Compiling RoboVM app, this could take a while, especially the first time round
[DEBUG] Compiling com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.style.BCStyle (ios thumbv7)
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000013775c21a, pid=234, tid=6403
# etc...
```